# String match regex with one typo in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am matching whole words in a sentence using preg_match in PHP. This works fine. But it happens that sometimes a word is not matched due to one typo. For instance the official word is "Prader Willi syndrome". But then a biologist types "Prader-Willi syndrome" (the extra hyphen).

Is it possible to match words where you allow one typo using a regex?

Comment: a hyphen instead of a space can be accounted for; for generic typos it will be next to impossible.

Comment: @user you mean this http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/69